# How to run helloWorld using Maven californium - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, coap, californium

I am new to Java environment,
I'm trying to run a **Coap** server using **Californium**
https://github.com/eclipse-californium/californium

I cloned the git repo. then ran `mvn clean install` in the repo folder.
I now want to run the hello world demo in `californium/demo-apps/cf-helloworld-server/`

what is the next step?

I opened the folder `cd demo-apps/cf-helloworld-server`
then ran

- `mvn clean install`
- `mvn compile`

it worked without errors,
now how to run the server?

if I run:

```
java target.classes.org.eclipse.californium.examples.HelloWorldServer
```

I get this error

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.eclipse.californium.examples.Server
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/californium/elements/exception/ConnectorException
```

Comment: Two things to note: 1. `mvn compile` is not needed once you have run `mvn clean install` and 2. In case of maven you don't actually run a java class, but instead run the executable (`jar` in your case) that was generated by the `mvn clean install` that you ran. You can find the jar directly under the `target` directory and execute it with `java -jar <jar filepath>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please build not only a demo-app, that doesn't work from scratch.

Instead build the parent (root folder of californium) with

mvn clean install

Afterwards change to the app directory, e.g. "demo-apps/cd-helloworld-server".
There  you start the server with

"java -jar target/cf-helloworld-server-3.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

and you get the output:

> Californium (Cf) Server-Starter (c) 2020, Bosch.IO GmbH and others
>
> Usage: Server (HelloWorldServer|MulticastTestServer)

Follow the usage:

"java -jar target/cf-helloworld-server-3.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar HelloWorldServer"

and you run the HelloWorldServer.